# component above material top bar? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im using `react-navigation/material-top-bar` to navigate between screens, the problem with this is that im also using a component `bottomsheet` when it reaches at the top of the screen the tab covers it, is there a way to put the bottom sheet above the tab bar?

[image]

the code, heres the app:

```
render() {
return (
  <>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab_Navigator></Tab_Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  </>
);
```

```
heres tab:

    return(
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name = "Tracks" component = {Tracks}></Tab.Screen>
            <Tab.Screen name = "Chao" component = {Chao}></Tab.Screen>
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )

and this is Tracks:

     <View style = {{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "black"}}>
                    <BottomSheet
                        ref = {ref => (this.sheetref = ref)}
                        initialSnap = {1}
                        snapPoints = {[Dimensions.get("window").height - StatusBar.currentHeight, 95]}
                        renderHeader = {() => <Player_Header {...props}></Player_Header>}
                        renderContent = {() => <Track_Zone {...props}></Track_Zone>}
                        enabledContentGestureInteraction = {false}
                        onOpenEnd = {this.hide_icon}
                        onCloseEnd = {this.show_icon}>
                    </BottomSheet>
                </View>
            </>
```